# Select only categorical columns from a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I know how to select numeric fields from one dataframe to another.

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
```

I was thinking there should be a similar way to select categorical fields, as such.

```
df2 = df.select_dtypes(include=['category'])
```

Of course that doesn't work.  Is there a way to do this?  I have a data frame with float64 and object datatypes.

Also, I'm trying to split these into continuous and discrete types, and hopefully bin the continuous data points.  The line below seems to work fine.

```
df1['price_bins'] = pd.cut(df1.PRICE, bins=15)
```

Is this the preferred way to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

to find out categorical values just replace the word 'categorical' in your code to 'object'

```
df2 = df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have version 0.23.4 of `pandas` installed, and this is the help documentation from `select_dtypes()`:

> ### Notes
>
> - To select all *numeric* types, use `np.number` or `'number'`
> - To select strings you must use the `object` dtype, but note that   this will return *all* object dtype columns
> - See the `numpy dtype hierarchy   <http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html>`__
> - To select datetimes, use `np.datetime64`, `'datetime'` or   `'datetime64'`
> - To select timedeltas, use `np.timedelta64`, `'timedelta'` or   `'timedelta64'`
> - To select Pandas categorical dtypes, use `'category'`
> - To select Pandas datetimetz dtypes, use `'datetimetz'` (new in
>     0.20.0) or `'datetime64[ns, tz]'`

The second-to-last is the one you're looking for: use just `'category'` instead of `['category']`; i.e. don't wrap in square brackets.

Comment: I actually tried that before posting my question.  df2 = df.select_dtypes(include='category')

df2.shape
(236074, 0)

Comment: Then there are no `Series` in the `DataFrame` that have `dtype == pd.Categorical` ‍♂️

Comment: Now that I re-read your question, you say

"I have a data frame with `float64` and `object` data types"

so of course it will return no `Series` that is of type `pd.Categorical`; there are only `float64` and `object` type `Series` in the `DataFrame`

Comment: Well, I thought at least some are categorical.  I have one field with S303, 
S89, S4, S45, and about a dozen other codes.  This has a datatype of object.  I thought these, at least, should be categorical.  I think Python is making a guess about the data when it is loaded from the CSV to the DF.  Maybe my approach is wrong.  I'll do more research on this.  Thanks for the helping hand here!!